# Why jquery plugin is not repeating after it's been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to find a solution to repeat action when user did already one time. For example, when user comes on site there is carousel which can be swiped, slided, and eventually opened in order to see full gallery. I have managed to do that but when the user made this action and closes modal box, he is not able to repeat the same action. Anyone has idea how to solve it?

Here is js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // - jQuery

    // Swipe feature
    $('#myCarousel').swiperight(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
    });
    $('#myCarousel').swipeleft(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
    });

    // Swipe feature for modal
    $('#modal-carousel').swiperight(function () {
        $('#modal-carousel').carousel('prev');
        console.log('swipe_right');
    });
    $('#modal-carousel').swipeleft(function () {
        $('#modal-carousel').carousel('next');
        console.log('swipe_left');
    });

    // Additional toolbar with "close" button appears
    $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('modal').modal('show');
        $('#toolbar').css('display', 'block'); //.css('position','fixed')
        $('.carousel-inner').css('overflow', 'visible');
        // Remove entirely in final version
        $('.item').css('background', 'none')
        console.log('fires toolbar');
    });

    $(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('modal').modal('show');
        $('#toolbar').css('display', 'none'); //.css('position','absolute')
        $('.carousel-inner').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        // Remove entirely in final version
        $('.item').css('background', '#60b1ff')
        console.log('closes toolbar when modal is closed');
    });

    // Closes modal on toolbar
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });

    /* Modal Carousel from version 3. adjusted to version 2.3 */

    /* activate the carousel */
    $("#modal-carousel").carousel({
        interval : false,
    });

    /* when clicking a image */
    $(".thumbnail").click(function () {
        var content = $(".carousel-inner");

        content.empty();

        var id = this.id;
        var repo = $('#img-repo .item');
        var repoCopy = repo.filter('#' + id).clone();
        var active = repoCopy.first();
        var next = repoCopy.last();

        active.addClass('active');

        content.append(repoCopy);

        // show the modal
        $('#modal-gallery').modal('show');

    });

    // Carousel pause - prevents automatic slideshow
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause : true,
        interval : false
    });

    // Close window
    $('.modal-backdrop').modal({
        show : false
    });

}); //end of script
```

Problem is at the `content.empty();` which after executed action stays empty. Any ideas how to solve this?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ax98jm2w/)

[Fiddle 2 with working carousel. Just imagine that you are able to open one of those images in modal.](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ax98jm2w/9/)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample fiddle in order to reproduce your issue...

Comment: Hi Robert, there is fiddle with my code. 

or even better you can take a look here just imagine that you are able to open one of those images from the carousel.

link: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ax98jm2w/9/

Comment: It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ax98jm2w/10/

Comment: did you changed the code?

Comment: Yes i change the way the scripts are included...did it work now, right?..if so i can post it as an answer